# Unsigneds in order to prevent negative numbers

Tags: language-agnostic, unsigned

*let's hope I can make this non-sujective*

Here's the thing: Sometimes, on fixed-typed languages, I restrict input on methods and functions to positive numbers by using the `unsigned` types, like `unsigned int` or `unsigned double`, etc.

Most libraries, however, doesn't seem to think that way. Take C# `string.Length`. It's a integer, even though it can never be negative. Same goes for C/C++: `sqrt` input is an `int` or a `double`. I know there are reasons for this ... for example your argument might be read from a file and (no idea why) you may prefer to send the value directly to the function and check for errors latter (or use a try-catch block).

So, I'm assuming that libraries are way better designed than my own code. So what are the reasons against using unsigned numbers to represent positive numbers? It's because of overflow when we cast then back to signed types?

Comment: I know I might have answered my own question. Still, I want to know what other reasons might be there besides overflowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of C & C++, a lot of the libraries existed before `unsigned` entered the language, so vanilla `int` was all that was available.  Newer additions to the libraries will use unsigned types such as `size_t`.

In the case of .NET, there are languages (e.g. Visual Basic) that don't have the concept of unsigned integers (at least as language features -- they can of course use the System.UInt32, etc. types).

Comment: Good answer. I would only add to this that for core .NET methods there's no need to distinguish signed/unsigned as a type signature since this would add unnecessary complexity to languages that would otherwise just have an Integer/Numeric type.

Comment: Another point is that the .NET classes have bounds checking so that negative indices will cause exceptions.

Comment: In other words, do you believe I should use unsigned in other to avoid negative input in my function/methods?

Comment: @Bruno: I meant that using a negative index in C# (or other .NET languages) will be caught by the runtime, in contrast with C or C++ where using a negative index may not be caught immediately: array[-1] may well be a valid memory reference, just not one that returns valid data.  My practice is to use int in C# because that's what the BCL uses, and to use unsigned in C & C++ because the OS is more likely to complain about me referencing array[4294967295] than array[-1].

Answer (score 2):

Just to correct one part of what you said: in C and C++, `sqrt` always takes a floating point type (float, double or long double), and the language doesn't include any unsigned floating point types. C99 adds `csqrt` to deal with the `complex` types, but these (again) are based on floating point types -- and since they deal with complex numbers, they can produce perfectly reasonable results from an input with a negative real part anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I generally tend to go for `int` for loop iterators, unless I explicitly need large values (in which case `size_t` or `ssize_t` is probably an even better option given 64 bit architectures).
Part because the `unsigned` is more typing work :) But also, when counting down:

```
for(unsigned int i=100; i>=0; --i) 
{
    printf("%i\n");
}
```

Guess what will happen :) Even though you don't expect negative numbers, you can't signal them either if they happen. Which is sometimes very unsafe.

Comment: Agreed... I find that the accidental underflow of an unsigned usually produces a harder to find bug than simply using a negative int when you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

System level languages will always require different signed and unsigned integer types.
It's how we are able to derive efficiency at the hardware level.

However,  an unsigned integer type, does not simply mean "not negative".
You should avoid using unsigned integer types  **unless**
you need 2's compliment arithmetic,  or a bit pattern.

The main motivation for sticking with signed numbers is that when you mix signed and unsigned numbers you get into trouble.  The rules are very surprising, and  in languages like C++, they correlate highly with bugs.

You should instead rely on static/dynamic checking of the type's value, to ensure that it is not a negative number.

Comment: Could you expand on the possible surprises?

Comment: See: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything
9:50, 42:40, and 1:02:50